# Pandas df manipulation - breaking data into 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example data frame with 2 indicating columns (example below, product and version - where version numbers can only be 1 or 2) and a 3rd column with actual data.

```
product       version       data    
  a              1          8000
  a              2          1000
  b              1          4000
  b              2          2000
  c              1          9000
  c              2          1000
  d              1          2500
  d              2          3000
```

I am trying to manipulate my df so that instead of the above, I have 2 data columns (say data1 and data2) which correspond to the version of that product (thereby making the version column redundant). See below:

```
product       data1       data2    
  a           8000        1000
  b           4000        2000
  c           9000        1000
  d           2500        3000
```

Is anyone able to advise on a simple solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pivot the table using pandas function `.pivot`

```
>>> result = df.pivot(index='product', columns='version', values='data').reset_index()
>>> result
version product     1     2
0             a  8000  1000
1             b  4000  2000
2             c  9000  1000
3             d  2500  3000

>>> result.index.name = None
>>> result.columns = ['product', 'data1', 'data2']
>>> result
  product  data1  data2
0       a   8000   1000
1       b   4000   2000
2       c   9000   1000
3       d   2500   3000
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to use pandas method `pivot` and then rename columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = df.pivot(index='product', values='data', columns='version').reset_index(drop=True)
data.columns = ['data1', 'data2']
data.index.name = 'product'
```

Comment: Please remove the construction of the dataframe and keep only the last 3 lines of your code - *it confuses people and they may not upvote your correct answer*. (I edited the question, so you may copy data from the question into the clipboard and then use the `df = pd.read_clipboard(r"\s\s+")` command to obtain the original dataframe.)

Comment: Okay, I have removed those lines.